# Yarn.lock is modified on dev/live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

This is quite strange problem. I believe it was not in there before (in previous versions of yarn or it's some package problem). I'm using yarn on MacOS and deploy application to live server. Yarn on both is latest 1.12.1

On localhost:

1. I removed `node_modules` directory
2. I removed also `yarn.lock`
3. I run `yarn install` to install all fresh dependencies

Now I deployed code to live server (with `yarn.lock`) and:

1. I removed `node_modules` directory
2. I run `yarn install` to install all fresh dependencies - it should use `yarn.lock` and not modify it

The problem is that on live server `yarn.lock` file is modified.

When I run `git diff` I'm getting (beginning of diff):

```
   resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@xtuc/long/-/long-4.2.2.tgz#d291c6a4e97989b5c61d9acf396ae4fe133a718d"
   integrity sha512-NuHqBY1PB/D8xU6s/thBgOAiAP7HOYDQ32+BFZILJ8ivkUkAHQnWfn6WhL79Owj1qmUnoN/YPhktdIoucipkAQ==

-abbrev@1:
-  version "1.1.1"
-  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.1.1.tgz#f8f2c887ad10bf67f634f005b6987fed3179aac8"
-  integrity sha512-nne9/IiQ/hzIhY6pdDnbBtz7DjPTKrY00P/zvPSm5pOFkl6xuGrGnXn/VtTNNfNtAfZ9/1RtehkszU9qcTii0Q==
-
 accepts@~1.3.4, accepts@~1.3.5, accepts@~1.3.7:
   version "1.3.7"
   resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.7.tgz#531bc726517a3b2b41f850021c6cc15eaab507cd"
@@ -1071,19 +1066,11 @@ anymatch@~3.1.1:
     normalize-path "^3.0.0"
     picomatch "^2.0.4"

-aproba@^1.0.3, aproba@^1.1.1:
+aproba@^1.1.1:
```

As you can see on live server `abbrev@1` is removed from here, and `aproba` changes from `aproba@^1.0.3, aproba@^1.1.1:` to `aproba@^1.1.1:`.

What could be the reason of it? Before it was not happenning and always when I commited modified `yarn.lock` it was not modified on live server.

Comment: On the server use `--frozen-lockfile`

Comment: Why delete `yarn.lock`?  Of course you'll get new versions: the newest version of each dependency matching your package.json, e.g. caret (^), tilde (~), .x.x, etc.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147

Comment: Did you also perhaps manually edit the package.json or added a package via `npm` per accident? This may lead to an out-of-sync package.json / yarn.lock file, `yarn install` will happily create an updated version of the yarn.lock file. Only `--frozen-lockfile` will show you that there is an error. (Check also if your yarn.lock changes on your localhost if run `yarn install`.)

Comment: @k0pernikus No, i don't use `npm` commands, I use `yarn` for everything from a long time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

as per the [yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/):

> If you need reproducible dependencies, which is usually the case with the continuous integration systems, you should pass `--frozen-lockfile` flag.

This is the behavior of `yarn install`:

> Install all the dependencies listed within `package.json`
>   in the local `node_modules` folder.
>
> The `yarn.lock` file is utilized as follows:
>
> - If yarn.lock is present and is enough to satisfy all the dependencies
>     listed in `package.json`, the exact versions recorded in `yarn.lock` are
>     installed, and yarn.lock will be unchanged. Yarn will not check for
>     newer versions.
> - If `yarn.lock` is absent, or is not enough to satisfy
>     all the dependencies listed in `package.json` (for example, if you
>     manually add a dependency to package.json), Yarn looks for the newest
>     versions available that satisfy the constraints in `package.json`. The
>     results are written to yarn.lock.
>
> If you want to ensure `yarn.lock` is
>   not updated, use `--frozen-lockfile`.

Comment: While this does kind of address the questions, the actual issue is that the OP's package.json and yarn.lock are obviously out of sync (namely because the OP deleted yarn.lock).  If the package.json is modified externally (not by yarn, e.g. an editor, via npm, or for some reason deleted), then of course the yarn.lock will be updated when yarn install is issued.

Comment: @avejidah OP stated that they pushed the updated version to the live server. Here, just running `yarn install` may mutate the yarn.lock file. Only `--frozen-lockfile` ensures that it remains untouched.

Comment: From the doc you linked (and described in the issue you linked in the comment), "If yarn.lock is present and is enough to satisfy all the dependencies listed in package.json, the exact versions recorded in yarn.lock are installed, and yarn.lock will be unchanged. Yarn will not check for newer versions."  E.g. if yarn.lock is modified, then it's out of sync with package.json.  In other words, "yarn.lock is absent, or is not enough to satisfy all the dependencies listed in package.json."

Comment: @avejidah Gist is, you cannot trust `yarn install` not the update the yarn.lock as it will write an updated `yarn.lock` if the package.json / yarn.lock are out of sync. So even if it was the case that there may be an out-of-sync package.json, using `--frozen-lockfile` would actually allow to discover that due to the error.

Comment: Right, I see that and you're completely correct.  I'm not disagreeing, I'm just pointing that if the yarn.lock file is being modified that it's indicative of a workflow issue/user error: the package and lockfile are out of sync.  How did that happen?  Deleting yarn.lock is definitely suspect and definitely a bad workflow/user error.

Comment: @avejidah True. It may be good to point out that one should rather update a library through `yarn upgrade`, though it'd dilute this answer.

Comment: @avejidah Just to be clear I removed `yarn.lock` just for testing this issue. And it was not out of sync as I commited this to live server as I wrote in my question

Comment: @k0pernikus Thanks for the answer. I've already read before your comments here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4379#issuecomment-380375196 I will test this tomorrow - probably this is the solution. Do you have any idea - was this from the beginning of yarn or it was introduced in some release? In PHP we have `composer.lock` and it is never updated when we run `composer install` so it's pretty strange that when you install packages via yarn it automatically updates lock file if you don't add this `--frozen-lockfile`

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I feel you :D I also come from a php-background and was used to composer, so I was very perplexed by the JavaScript workflow. `yarn` requires the `--frozen-lockfile` flag since a very long time. npm also has the weirdness that you must use `npm ci` over `npm install` to not mutate the package.lock json, and that is a rather new feature. (Don't even get me started on shrinkwrap.) Apparently, a big chunk of the JavaScript developers are fine with randomly updating dependencies ;)

Comment: Tested it today and it seems adding `--frozen-lockfile` solves the problem

Comment: But just.... why? The whole point of the lockfile wasn't that to have reproducible installs?

Comment: @RuneKaagaard ‍♂️ https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147